# Python - Searching text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a programme that requires me to iterate through a text file and complete a sum, any values that are below the required value need to be added to an invoice file. However the code that I have created only writes one product rather then every one that is required to be restocked.

Here is the main code:

```
def createRestockFile(productName,minimumStockLevel,currentStock, amountNeeded,costToUs):
    with open("invoice.txt", 'r+') as f:
        f.write("#Product Name\tMinimum Stock Level\tCurrent Stock Level\tAmount Needed\tCost To Re-Order \n")
        f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (productName,minimumStockLevel,currentStock,amountNeeded,costToUs))

def checkStock():
    with open("stock.txt",'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            if int(line.split()[2]) < int(line.split()[5]):
                amountNeeded = int(line.split()[5]) - int(line.split()[2])
                total = '£{:,.2f}'.format(float(line.split()[3])*amountNeeded)
                createRestockFile(line.split()[1],line.split()[5],line.split()[2],amountNeeded,total)
                print(line.split())


def startProgramme():
    yesInput = ["yes", "yes please", "y"]
    noInput = ["no","nope","n"]
    print("Welcome to Sean's Stock re-order programme")
    choice = input("Would you like to check which products need re-ordering ")
    if choice in yesInput:
        checkStock()
    elif choice in noInput:
        import time
        print("Thank you for using Sean's re-order programme")
        print("Ending Programme")
        time.sleep(0.6)
        exit()



startProgramme()
```

**Here is the invoice file:**

```
#Product Name   Minimum Stock Level Current Stock Level Amount Needed   Cost To Re-Order 
Wispa   16  6   10  £3.4003.40
```

**Here is the stock file:**

```
45678948    Twix    12  0.42    0.65    25  50  
12345670    Wispa   6   0.34    0.85    16  40  
26073125    Crunchie    37  0.37    0.69    8   43      
24785122    Flake   47  0.24    0.65    10  35  
45678914    Snickers    42  0.46    0.75    8   32      
78945617    Maltesers   78  0.32    0.56    12  65      
85146945    Galaxy  57  0.32    0.76    9   54
```

With the given values in the stock file, the programme should add both the twix and wispa to the invoice file, however only the wispa is added. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the mode you open the invoice.txt in. For the function, you need to change it from `r+` to `a+`; it is writing the twix invoice then deleting it and then writing wispa.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

I have moved the position in the code where you open the invoice file into the main program so you can keep your opening mode "w+". Note also that I wrote code so that you split the input line only once (saves time and makes the code shorter)

```
def createRestockFile(productName,minimumStockLevel,currentStock, amountNeeded,costToUs, f):
    f.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (productName,minimumStockLevel,currentStock,amountNeeded,costToUs) + "\n")


def checkStock(invoiceFile):
    with open("stock.txt",'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split()
            if int(splits[2]) < int(splits[5]):
                amountNeeded = int(splits[5]) - int(splits[2])
                total = '£{:,.2f}'.format(float(splits[3])*amountNeeded)
                createRestockFile(splits[1],splits[5],splits[2],amountNeeded,total, invoiceFile)
                print(splits)


def startProgramme():
    yesInput = ["yes", "yes please", "y"]
    noInput = ["no","nope","n"]
    print("Welcome to Sean's Stock re-order programme")
    choice = input("Would you like to check which products need re-ordering ")
    if choice in yesInput:
        invoice_f = open("invoice.txt", 'w+')
        invoice_f.write("#Product Name\tMinimum Stock Level\tCurrent Stock Level\tAmount Needed\tCost To Re-Order \n")
        checkStock(invoice_f)
        invoice_f.close()
    elif choice in noInput:
        import time
        print("Thank you for using Sean's re-order programme")
        print("Ending Programme")
        time.sleep(0.6)
        exit()

startProgramme()
```